# Updateorcreate always create | How to use it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to use updateOrCreate function in an observer.
So i have this function :

```
 $transportpropremoyenaller = Transport::updateOrCreate(
        ['centre_id' => $gestionsejour->centre_id, 'allerouretour' => 
'Aller', 'date' => $gestionsejour->datedebut],
        ['ville' =>  \Config::get('constants.transport.0'), 'tarif' => '0']
    );
```

I use this function in GestionsejourObserver like that :

```
 public function created(Gestionsejour $gestionsejour)
{
    return $this->addtransportpropremoyen($gestionsejour);
}
```

When i create a new object updateOrCreate never update and always create a new one.

Gestionsejour model is:

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'datefin',
    'user_id',
    'agrement',
    'centre_id',
    'datedebut',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at',
    'dureesejour',
    'periodesejour',
    'complet',
];

public function centre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Centre::class, 'centre_id');
}

public function getDatedebutAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;
}

public function setDatedebutAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['datedebut'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
}

public function getDatefinAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? Carbon::parse($value)->format(config('panel.date_format')) : null;
}

public function setDatefinAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['datefin'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('panel.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Myabe it's not possible to send 3 attributes or there is a problem with date. I don't know. I'm reading laravel doc but don't understand what is the problem in this simple function.

Comment: Check datedebut in your database, IMHO I think they are all different int the time part even at the same year, month and day. If so the update part does not find an equal value all the time.

Comment: Date in DB is at date format so they is not time part. Just Mont , day and years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problems lies in this method `getDatedebutAttribute`
When you run the following piece of code, the accessor is also used, meaning you're searching for d-m-y format, visualised below.

```
'date' => $gestionsejour->datedebut // '03-08-2019' <- because of getDatedebutAttribute
```

Maybe you can create a helper mehtod instead of using accessors and mutators. Leaving the data on the model the same as inside your database.
another thing you can do on your model is telling which columns are dates with $dates, so they will automatically be Carbon Objects

```
// Model.php

/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'datedebut',
];


public function formattedDateDebut()
{
    return $this->datedebut ? $this->datedebut->format('d-m-y') : null;
}
```

And use it inside your views like this.

```
{{ $gestionsejour->formattedDateDebut() }}
```

This way you also dont need the `setDatedebutAttribute` anymore, because Y-m-d is the default format when you use it here `'date' => $gestionsejour->datedebut`

Comment: It was that. Date was problem. I just transformed the date for to bypass the accessor and send it to Y-m-d format in my function and it's ok now. It's more simple because to many template use accessor date in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even better: you can consider something like this.

```php
    public function setTypeAttribute($value) {
        $typeVal = array_search($value, self::TYPE);
        if ($typeVal === false)
            $typeVal = $value;
        $this->attributes['type'] = $value;
    }
```

You will need to bypass the mutation because this is what happening behind the scene for updateOrCreate:

```php
    public static function updateOrCreate($where, $fields) {
        $record = self::where($where)->first();
        if ($record) {
            $record->update($fields);
        }
        else
            $record = self::create(array_merge($where, $fields));
        return $record;
    }
```

Take note that for $where, there shouldn't be mutation, but for $fields, it will be mutated before hitting the database, the problem arises when you merge $where & $fields, you are mixing the unmutated value into $fields.

Or solution 2, have the pre-mutated value appended to 2nd param of updateOrCreate(). Eg.

```php
updateOrCreate(['date' => $mutatedValue], [
  'date' => $premutatedValue
])
```

Hope it helps.